# Room: @Embedded vs @TypeConverters

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

If we have @Entity in Room in which there are complex objects as fields, we can use 2 approaches:

@Embedded - as I understand it, if you mark the field with this annotation, then Room will save all the fields that are inside the object as fields of the Entity itself, and then retrieve everything correctly.

@TypeConverters - here we write our own converter, which in most cases boils down to the usual parsing of an object into a Json string.

Actually the question:

What is the fundamental difference? Why not write @Embedded everywhere and not worry about converters? When is it better to write your own converter, and when is it better to use @Embedded, and what are the advantages and disadvantages of these approaches?

Comment: These are apples and pears... which should be the obvious difference. And your assumption about `@TypeConverter` appears just wrong to me (as handling JSON is just as effective as NoSQL).

Comment: That is why I ask this question. I do not know difference, and i think my knowledge of these annotations are wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If we have @Entity in Room in which there are complex objects as fields, we can use 2 approaches

Actually there is one more approach to be mentioned here - is saving complex object in separate table and linking to it with foreign key (as usual `id` with `Int` or `Long` type, often autogenerated).

- If complex object has its own value and has several connections with other objects, consider using separate table and foreign key. Example: You have complex object `User` and couple of another - `UserGroup` (and field: `user`) and `Document` (field: `author`). Using separate table `User` you can change user's name only in one place and you don't need to touch two other tables (but you should do that with `@Embedded` approach).
- Widely-used use-case for `Type-converter` - is converting type `Date` to integer, since Sqlite doesn't know how to save this type using its own type's system. `@Embedded` is not helpful in this case.
- Another widely-used use-case for `Type-converter` - is persisting in database complex nested structures, often gotten from backend API (JSON serialisation). But this approach is fragile if you later decide to deal with part of these nested structures independently (query to them, for example).
- One more widely-used (as for my taste - used too much) use-case for `Type-converter` is persisting List or Array of some objects in one field. But often this approach could be replaced with using separate tables and foreign keys (if these objects form the List have its own value).
- If in more than one @Entity you use `@Embedded` on the same complex object it's a sign you should consider option with separate table and foreign key, since it's a waste of space and in some way violation of principles of DB tables' normalisation. For example, if some complex object has N fields and you use it as a `@Embedded` field at two other tables that means that SQLite generates N additional columns in these two tables.
- It should be mentioned that `@Embedded` is widely used in Room's data-classes with @Relation (ROOM's analogues for JOINs). There they are really helpful and help a lot to keep these data-classes' code short and simple. In that way @Embedded doesn't add any duplication to tables' structures (since it affects only on objects in memory) as it does when it's used inside class annotated with @Entity.

Answer (score 1):

The actual difference is, that `@TypeConverter` uses the same table and `@Embedded` uses a separate table. Even if `@TypeConverter` can be abused to serialize/de-serialize JSON, this only makes sense while not needing to query for values in there - but as soon as one wants to query that data, it's a whole lot less effort, when it is backed by an actual table, which one can run SQL against (instead of traversing all records and decoding the JSON). Actually JSON is a data-format, not a data-type.

Just take for example the WordPress post-meta ...this also is JSON stored in an SQL database. Also here it is technically possible, but it's the reason why the performance is below par.

Proper use of a `@TypeConverter` would eg. be converting from `String` to `BigDecimal`.

Comment: `@Embedded` saves the properties as columns (with an optional prefix) in the same table as the entity. It's *embedded* in the entity. `TypeConverter` serializes an object into a single value in a single column.

Comment: It's rather an abuse when `@TypeConverter` is being used to serialize/de-serialize JSON, instead of converting data-types... else it might eventually have another name. This approach only has a limited application, not even starting with relations, where it also falls short. As my WordPress example might suggest, it may make sense for unstructured data, but at the cost of performance.